# htaccess help needed to change just parts of the url

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to use htaccess to redirect to another url that is just partly different?

Here is my task:

url/article/yearmonthnumber/title needs to be redirected to
url/article/monthname-year/title

So the task is to only change the date part.
There are about 8000 post on this site and some from a specific year need to be redirected like described, so that external links do not go to a 404 page.

To close out misunderstandings:

url/article/200302/title needs to be redirected to
url/article/february-2003/title

and of course there are a number of posts in february 2003, all with different titles.

I hope, I could explain what my question is.

Thanx
mxmanuel

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to the server's config, which will allow you to create a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html), I think you'll need to create a rule for each of the 12 months:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})01/(.*)$ /article/january-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})02/(.*)$ /article/february-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})03/(.*)$ /article/march-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})04/(.*)$ /article/april-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})05/(.*)$ /article/may-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})06/(.*)$ /article/june-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})07/(.*)$ /article/july-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})08/(.*)$ /article/august-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})09/(.*)$ /article/september-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})10/(.*)$ /article/october-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})11/(.*)$ /article/november-$1/$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-4]{4})12/(.*)$ /article/december-$1/$2 [L,R]
```